# unsure about initializing one dimensional char array with array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings, u-boot

As per my understanding array of strings can be initialized as shown below or using two dimensional array. Please tell is there any other possibility.

```
char *states[] = { "California", "Oregon", "Washington", "Texas" };
```

I have observed in U-boot source that environment variables are stored in one dimensional array as shown [here](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=common/env_common.c;h=be64d1307b96441ba184e080263541d7860f7dd2;hb=3d35d87d5482de23cd5dc4d7721b1086107cae50#l60):

```
uchar default_environment[] = {
#ifdef  CONFIG_BOOTARGS
    "bootargs="     CONFIG_BOOTARGS     "\0"
#endif
#ifdef  CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND
    "bootcmd="      CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND   "\0"
#endif 
...
    "\0"
};
```

Can you help me understand this?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: Which part of the code in that link are you referring to?

Comment: The technique used in `uchar default_environment[]` has less efficient random access, e.g. if you want to find a string you have to search through from the start.  I'd recommend not doing this unless you're coding in an extreme situation where nanoseconds and bytes matter (and even then, maybe not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per my understanding array of strings can be initialized as shown below or using two dimensional array. Please tell is there any other possibility.
>
> I have observed in U-boot source that environment variables are stored in one dimensional array.

If you have the implication that this `default_environment` is an array of strings, then it is *not*. This has nothing to do with array of strings initialization as in your first example.

You can try remove all `#ifdef` and `#endif`, then it'd be clear that `default_environment` is simply a concatenation of individual strings. For instance, `"bootargs="     CONFIG_BOOTARGS     "\0"`. Notice the `\0` at the end, it will ensure that the string assigned to `default_environment` will not get pass the first line, given `CONFIG_BOOTARGS` is defined.

```
uchar default_environment[] = {
#ifdef  CONFIG_BOOTARGS
    "bootargs="     CONFIG_BOOTARGS     "\0"
#endif
#ifdef  CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND
    "bootcmd="      CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND   "\0"
#endif 
...
    "\0"
};
```

Comment: Can I use default_environment[0], default_environment[1] to access different strings.

Comment: No, you can't. This is a single character array but with embedded NULL ('\0') characters in between. So you can think of it a _serial_ of strings consecutively. If you access `default_environment[0]`, you are still accessing the first character, not the first string per se.

Comment: You may want to inspect that uboot file (common-env_common.c), see how they parse the `default_environment` variable, for example see function `env_get_addr`.

Answer (score 3):

A "string" is effectively nothing more than a pointer to a sequence of chars terminated by a char with the value `0` (note that the sequence **must** be within a single object).

```
char a[] = {65, 66, 67, 0, 97, 98, 99, 0, 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', 0, 0};
/*                      ^              ^                                ^  ^ */
```

In the above array we have four elements with value `0` ... so you can see that as 4 strings

```
// string 1
printf("%s\n", a); // prints ABC on a ASCII computer

// string 2
printf("%s\n", a + 4); // prints abc on a ASCII computer

// string 3
printf("%s\n", a + 8); // prints foobar

// string 4
printf("%s\n", a + 14); // prints empty string
```

Comment: Does this answer any of the question?

Comment: @artm you have to wait for OP reaction. My intent is to help understanding embedded zeroes as in the U-boot source code.

Comment: It's just  hard to read ASCII code (ABC and foo/ bar interleaved with zero, while Q is about uboot variable string). May be just `A`', `B`, .. `\0` would be easier to read. But I see your intention now.

Answer (score 1):

They are not creating an array of strings there, such as your `char *states[]`, it's a single string that is being created (as a `char[]`). The individual 'elements' inside the string are denoted by zero-termination.

To translate your example

```
char *states[] = { "California", "Oregon", "Washington", "Texas" };
```

to their notation would be

```
char states[] = { "California" "\0" "Oregon" "\0" "Washington" "\0" "Texas" "\0" "\0" };
```

which is the same as

```
char states[] = { "California\0Oregon\0Washington\0Texas\0\0" };
```

You can use these by getting a pointer to the start of each zero-terminated block and then the string functions, such as `strlen` will read until they see the next `'\0'` character.

As for the why of it, [@M.M.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086390/unsure-about-initializing-one-dimensional-char-array-with-array-of-strings#comment55925378_34086390) gives some good indication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create and initialized array of string or hierarchy of arrays using pointers. Describing it in details in case someone needs it.

A single char

```
1. char states;
```

---

Pointer to array of chars.

```
2. char *states = (char *) malloc(5 * sizeof(char)):
```

Above statement is equivalent to `char states[5];`
Now its up to you if you initialize it with `strcpy()` like

```
strcpy(states, "abcd");
```

or use  direct values like this.

```
states[0] = 'a';
states[1] = 'b';
states[2] = 'c';
states[3] = 'd';
states[4] = '/0';
```

Although if you store any other char on index 4 it will work but it would be better to end this using null character `'\0'` .

---

Pointer to array of pointers or pointer to a matrix of chars

```
3. char ** states = (char **) malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));
```

It is an array of pointers i.e. each element is a pointer, which can point to or in other word hold a string etc. like

```
states[0] = malloc ( sizeof(char) * number ); 
states[1] = malloc ( sizeof(char) * number );
states[2] = malloc ( sizeof(char) * number );
states[3] = malloc ( sizeof(char) * number );
states[4] = malloc ( sizeof(char) * number );
```

Above statement is equivalent to `char states[5][number];`

Again its up to you how you initialize these pointers to strings i.e.

```
strcpy( states[0] , "hello");
strcpy ( states[1], "World!!");

states[2][0] = 'a';
states[2][1] = 'b';
states[2][2] = 'c';
states[2][3] = 'd';
states[2][4] = '\0';
```

Pointer to matrix of pointers or pointer to 3D chars

```
char *** states = (char ***) malloc(5 * sizeof(char**));
```

and so on. 
Actually each of these possibilities reaches somehow to pointers.

Comment: Is this answer relevant?

Answer (score 0):

If we simplify the question to what is the difference between initialising a `char *foo` versus a `char foo[100]` it might help. Check out the following code:

```
char buffer1[100] = "this is a test";
char *buffer2     = "this is a test";

int main(void)
{
    printf("buffer1 = %s\n", buffer1);
    buffer1[0] = 'T';
    printf("buffer1 = %s\n", buffer1);


    printf("buffer2 = %s\n", buffer2);
    buffer2[0] = 'T';
    printf("buffer2 = %s\n", buffer2); // this will fail
}
```

In the first case (`buffer1`) we initialise a character array with a string. The compiler will allocate 100 bytes for the array, and initialise the contents to "this is a test\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...". This array is modifiable like any other heap memory.

In the second case, we didn't allocate any memory for an array. All we asked the compiler to do is set aside enough memory for a pointer (4 or 8 bytes typically), then initialise that to point to a string stored somewhere else. Typically the compiler will either generate a separate code segment for the string, or else just store it inline with the code. In either case this string is *read-only*. So on the final line where I attempted to write to it, it caused a seg-fault.

That is the difference between initialising an array and a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The common technique is to use an array of pointers (note: this is different from a 2D array!) as:

```
char *states[] = { "California", "Oregon", "Washington", "Texas" };
```

That way, states is an array of 4 char pointer, and you use it simply `printf("State %s", states[i]);`

For completeness, a 2D array would be `char states[11][5]` with all rows having same length which is pretty uncommon, and harder to initialize.

But some special use cases or API(*) require (or return) a single char array where strings are (normally) terminated with `\0`, the array itself being terminated by an empty element, that it two consecutive `\0`. This representation allows a single allocation bloc for the whole array, when the common array of pointers has the array of pointers in one place and the strings themselves in another place. By the way, it is easy to rebuild an array of pointers from that 1D characater arrays with `\0` as separators, and it is generally done to be able to easily use the strings.

The last interesting point of the `uchar default_environment[]` technique is that it is a nice serialization: you can directly save it to a file and load it back. And as I have already said, the common usage is then to build an array of pointers to access easily to the individual strings.

---

(*) For example, the WinAPI functions `GetPrivateProfileSection` and `WritePrivateProfileSection` use such a representation to set or get a list of *key=value* strings in one single call.